# Why (must one) inherit from std::iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

To my understanding, iterators are a mechanism for providing an interface for the client to observe/iterate/pass through the contents of, for example, a custom collection, without breaking the information hiding principle. STL containers have iterators of their own, so we can use `for ( : )` and `for_each` loops on them with no problems.

My question initially was: why inherit from `std::iterator`? What additional functionality does it provide, in contrast to the following example:

**SimpleArray.h**

```
class SimpleArray
{
    int *arr;
    int n;
public:
    explicit SimpleArray(int = 1);
    ~SimpleArray();

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const SimpleArray&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, SimpleArray&);

    // encapsulated "iterator"
    class Observer
    {
        int *p;
    public:
        Observer(int *value = nullptr) : p(value) {}
        Observer& operator++() { p++; return *this; }
        Observer operator++(int) { int *temp = p; p++; return Observer(temp); }
        bool operator==(Observer other) const { return p == other.p; }
        bool operator!=(Observer other) const { return p != other.p; }
        int& operator*() const { return *p; }
    };

    Observer begin() { return Observer(arr); }
    Observer end() { return Observer(arr + n - 1); }
};
```

**Source.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    SimpleArray array(5);
    cin >> array;

    for (int item : array)
    {
        cout << item << " ";
    }

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

**Input**

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

`begin()` and `end()` functions are public and the `Observer` encapsulates all the necessary operators for the loop to function. The code compiled.

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

After trying the same with `std::for_each`

```
std::for_each(array.begin(), array.end(), [](int item) { cout << item << " "; });
```

I got some compiler errors:

```
C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected   Observer
C2938: '_Iter_cat_t<SimpleArray::Observer>' : Failed to specialize alias template
C2794: 'iterator_category': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_InIt>'
```

After reading about [for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), I found out its type parameters must meet some requirements, in short - to be Iterators.

My question now is: why is this function (and many others for certain) designed in a way that enforces this criteria, if it is fairly easy to create a *regular* class that provides the iterating functionality?

Comment: You don't have to inherit from `std::iterator`. In fact [it has been deprecated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) and should not be used.

Comment: Also your `Observer` does not have all the features that [a proper iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) must have. Inheriting from `std::iterator` gave you some of them, but it turned out too confusing and you should just do it by hand.

Comment: See `std::iterator_traits` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits

Comment: It's a convenience. If you prefer to write out the required typedefs yourself, go for it.

Comment: @nwp -- "deprecated" and "should not be used" are two completely different notions. "Deprecated" means "might be removed in the future". That's all. Some people have coding guidelines that say to never use deprecated features; that can result in a great deal of wheel-spinning in removing fully supported features from existing code before those changes are actually needed.

Comment: @PeteBecker The OP is considering writing a new iterator class for which I would say you should not use deprecated features. In your scenario you remove features from working code. Totally different scenario.

Comment: @nwp -- "it has been deprecated and should not be used" is, nevertheless, far too broad. Your correction is reasonable.

Comment: @nwp “…it has been deprecated…”-fact. “…and should not be used” I beg to disagree.

Comment: Pretty orthogonal to your question -- but in your example, if `n` is the size of the array, then your `end()` function should return `Observer(arr + n)`. `end()` normally returns a pointer "one past" the last item. As it is, a foreach loop will skip the last element -- and terrible things will happen if SimpleArray is empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only thing `std::iterator` provides are the member types `iterator_category`, `value_type`, `difference_type`, `pointer`, and `reference`, which are defined from the template parameters you provide. It doesn't have any other members. You can just define these member types yourself.

The real answer is that you don't need to inherit from `std::iterator` at all and it doesn't give you any real advantage. As far as C++ is concerned, if it looks like an iterator, it is an iterator. You just need to make sure your iterator type follows the concepts outlined here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator

`std::iterator` was deprecated in C++17 because of how relatively useless it is.

Comment: _"if it looks like an iterator, it is an iterator"_ or also known as [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)