# std::iterator is obsolete? What to use then?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++builder

```
for(std::vector<TMenuItem*>::iterator itItem=miMoreStylesArray.begin(); itItem<miMoreStylesArray.end(); itItem++) {
```

If std::iterator is being fazed out, then what do I use instead to iterate through vector?

Comment: `std::iterator` has nothing, or at best very little, to do with `std::vector::iterator`. It was meant as a base class for implementing one's own custom iterators. All it does is provide a bunch of typedefs. `std::vector::iterator` is not deprecated.

Comment: Related background on `std::iterator`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48446603/11082165

Comment: Regardless of the status of `std::vector::iterator`, `auto` makes your code a lot less noisy. To say nothing of range iteration syntax.

Comment: I think what's most important to mention regarding this question is that the code shown doesn't make any direct use of `std::iterator`.  Perhaps OP is confusing `std::iterator` with any symbol that's named `iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::iterator` has nothing to do with the iterators of standard library containers, such as `std::vector`.

While it is true that `std::iterator` is deprecated, `std::vector<TMenuItem*>::iterator` is certainly not.

The deprecation of `std::iterator` is only relevant to you if you used it as a base class to implement your own custom iterator class.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `std::iterator` was in order to assist you in implementing iterator traits.
However, you can easily implement your iterator and its inner traits by yourself without the need of `std::iterator`, see: [Preparation for std::iterator Being Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38103394/2085626).

The iterators inside the standard containers remain untouched, as is. Note that they are declared inside their respective containers (e.g. `vector<T>::iterator`) and not inside std directly.